# How to check xml object is empty or not in php

Tags: php, xml

```
if ($xml) {
    $emailId            = $xml->mail->id;
    $mailPassword       = $xml->mail->password;
    if (!empty($emailId) && !empty($mailPassword)) {
        $data['emailIdandPasswordCheck']    = 0;
    }
}
```

this is a condition in which we are checking the values are empty or not but it is not working
in this id is empty and password is not empty.
but everytime xml object is coming in both id and password
because of this both the things are coming as non empty.
what check i can use to check xml object is empty or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cast an array and you check the condition

```
$emailId  = (array)$emailId;
$mailPassword = (array)$mailPassword;
if (!empty($emailId) && !empty($mailPassword) ){

}
```

OR

```
$emailId  = (array)$emailId;
$mailPassword = (array)$mailPassword;
if (count($emailId)==0 && count($mailPassword)==0 ){

}
```

Comment: your answer is good but i found best way for my code it will be like we have to add (string) before $xml->mail->id and $xml->mail->password and this will change xml objects into string. So this will be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` instead of `empty()`

```
if (!isset($emailId) && !isset($mailPassword)) {
    $data['emailIdandPasswordCheck']    = 0;
}
```

OK. Here is what your code is doing.

```
$emailId            = $xml->mail->id;
```

This sets null in `$emailId` if there is no value.

```
$mailPassword       = $xml->mail->password;
```

And this sets null in `$mailPassword` if there is no value.

And your condition says

```
if emailId is non-empty and mailPassword is non-empty
```

And using `empty` always tells the conditions are true. Because `empty` returns `true` on `null`.
So instead using `isset` will solve the issue.
You can see the [comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
 if ($xml) {
        $emailId            = $xml->mail->id;
        $mailPassword       = $xml->mail->password;
        if ( $emailId !=null &&  $emailId !="" && $mailPassword!=null && $mailPassword!="" ) {
            $data['emailIdandPasswordCheck']    = 0;
        }
    }
```